# How to get the IMEI number for Nokia phones?

Tags: java-me, nokia

How do I get the [IMEI number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity) for Nokia phones?  I tried

```
StringBulder imei = ...........
imei.append(System.getProperty("phone.imei"));
imei.append(System.getProperty("com.nokia.imei"));
imei.append(System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.IMEI"));
```

All return null.

What could be the solution?

Comment: What handset?  It's different depending on if it's Series 40 or 60.

Answer (score 2):

On [Series 40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_40) phones this requires that your [MIDlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDlet) is signed to either an operator or manufacturer domain. Without a signed MIDlet you can't get the IMEI Number. See *[How to get IMEI in Java ME](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_get_IMEI_in_Java_ME)*.

Answer (score 0):

`com.nokia.mid.imei` is the correct one. On Symbian phones this is available on all security domains. On Series 40 phones it is available on only the manufacturer or operator security domains. This is likely to change to align with Symbian on the future Series 40 phones.

Answer (score 0):

See the same discussion, *[How do I get the IMEI number with J2ME](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?185616-Hw-i-get-imei-number-with-j2me)*, on the Nokia forum.